# Ajax saving but not sending CORS cookies from 127.0.0.1 to service

Tags: ajax, cookies, cross-domain

So I've been having issues sending cookies with a cross-domain request to a service. I've gotten to make it work in our CI environment, but not locally. Basically, I have an API at `api.service.com`, and it's accessed via AJAX calls run from clients at `webapp.service.com`. The API sets a cookie for `.service.com` via `set-cookie`. Then all subsequent calls to the API should include this cookie. This works as intended, when running from `webapp.service.com`. This will work in prod just fine. *However*, for obvious reasons, I'd like be able to develop the webapp locally, and run API calls against `api.service.com` from either local files or `localhost` service.

I understand that Chrome is a little iffy regarding saving cookies for local files, but I've addressed that, and it is not the issue. The cookie is, in fact, saving. It's just not sending that cookie with subsequent API calls. Here's the workflow I've got going on (with some genericized/censored product names):

An AJAX call POSTS to our API:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  crossDomain: true,
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true,
  },
  url: 'https://api.service.com/login',
  data: data,
  contentType:"text/plain",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data){
    ...
  }
});
```

The CORS stuff is set up to allow credentials and this origin (the allowed origin updates dynamically, doesn't use `*`. So we get this cookie back: `cookie:service-token=7f7d251ebeec37f7c0815....; SameSite=lax;Max-Age=2629744; domain=.service.com; path=/;`

It shows up in Chrome like this:

[Request cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuV2m.png)

I know for a fact that this actually works to save the cookie. However, perhaps not how I want. I go into Chrome's cookies, and it updates properly as seen:

[Chrome saved cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7ILt.png)

The problem I'm seeing there is that its "send for" value is "same-site connections only". I have no idea how to originally set that for Chrome to treat it as "any kind of connection." I think this is the reason that, when I send another AJAX call, that cookie is not included in the request.

I've seen other posts like this that were resolved by adding `crossDomain` and/or `withCredentials` to the AJAX call. This did not resolve it for me. This is a subsequent call to the API:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.service.com/getTheThing',
  crossDomain: true,
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
  },
  success: function(data){...}
});
```

The cookie is not included in this request, and thus fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, setting `SameSite=lax` was doing the opposite of what I thought it would. Removing that solved this issue.

Comment: I was surprised by this. Removing the setting to `lax` fixed the behavior in chrome Version 64.0.3282.168
`options.Cookie.SameSite = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.None;`